# Пересортировка деревьев

Tags: c, дерево

Допустим, у меня есть структура

```
struct name
{
    char ...
    char ...
    int ... 
};
```

И есть дерево, допустим АВЛ, заполненное элементами, имеющих тип данной структуры и, соответственно, отсортировано по одному из критериев. Чтобы пересортировать по другому параметру нужно пересобирать дерево или есть какой-то альтернативный путь?
Спасибо!

Comment: Ну, в качестве элементов можно использовать указатели на структуры...

Comment: @Harry, но ведь для доступа к нужному элементу придется перебирать все или я чего-то не понимаю

Comment: Посоветовали *наверное* держать постоянно **три** дерева, узлами которого будут указатели на структуры. **Но** для полного контроля нужно будет в структуре `name` хранить обратную связь. *(три указателя на три узла разных деревьев.)* Тут надо выбрать : память или скорость. Насколько часто нужно будет менять сортировку?

Comment: @AlexGlebe, вообще, там будет даже не 3 параметра, а 7. Менять сортировку по желанию пользователя. Еще такой вопрос, стоит ли смотреть в сторону b-tree?

Comment: Сколько у вас этих элементов? Миллионы? Грубо говоря, это большая база данных с миллионом записей и сотнями запросов в секунду? Какая реально частота запросов? Как часто изменяются данные? Добавляются, удаляются? Каким должно быть время отклика на выбор пользователя?

Comment: Если дерево обновляется достаточно редко, то для каждого критерия поиска кроме основного (по которому построено дерево) вы можете сделать массив указателей на элементы дерева, отсортированный по этому критерю и искать в нем двоичным поиском